# multiple middleware in nextjs 13 app directory not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I'm using Next.js 13 and I have a middleware function set up for Multilanguage. I want to add another middleware function, but it's not working for me. I guess I made a mistake in writing the middleware, but I'm not sure where. I don't get any error, it just doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

import acceptLanguage from 'accept-language'
import { fallbackLng, languages } from './app/i18n/settings'

acceptLanguage.languages(languages)

const cookieName = 'i18next'

export function middleware(req: any) {
let lng
if (req.cookies.has(cookieName)) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value)

    // automatic detect language with browser
    // if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get('Accept-Language'))
    
    if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng
    
    // Redirect if lng in path is not supported
    if (
        !languages.some(loc => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')
    ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
    }
    
    if (req.headers.has('referer')) {
        const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get('referer'))
        const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) => refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`))
        const response = NextResponse.next()
        if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer)
        return response
    }
    
    return NextResponse.next()

}

export function middleware2(request: NextRequest) {
if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/about')){
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
}

}

export const config = {
api: {
bodyParser: false,
},
matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)']

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Next.js does not support multiple middleware at the time I've written this answer but you can handle it yourself with following steps:

1. Create a middleware folder in the root directory (or src if using that in Next.js
2. create a config.ts file in this folder with below code

```
import {NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";
import {default as Authentication, matcher as AuthenticationMatcher} from "@/middleware/authentication";
// import {default as Logging, matcher as LoggingMatcher} from "@/middleware/localization";

interface middlewareType {
    middleware: (req: NextRequest) => Promise<NextResponse>
    matcher?: string | null | undefined
}

export const middleware: middlewareType[] = [
    {
        middleware: Authentication,
        matcher: AuthenticationMatcher
    },
    // {
    //     middleware: Logging,
    //     matcher: AuthenticationMatcher
    // },
]
```

3. create every middleware as you needed. as you can see I added Authentication and Localization middleware in its directory, each middleware file should have the following structure:

```
import {NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  // you codes ...
}
// updated 2024 - you be able to add a matcher for each middleware like this:
export const matcher = "/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)"
```

4. Finally, add a main middleware.ts file in the root of your project ([as explained in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware)) with the following content:

```
import type {NextRequest} from 'next/server'
import {middleware as activatedMiddleware} from '@/middleware/config'
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    // Load middleware functions
    const middlewareFunctions = activatedMiddleware
        .filter(m=> (!m.matcher || (!!m.matcher && new RegExp(m.matcher).test(req.nextUrl.toString()))))
        .map(m => m.middleware(req));

    // Option 1: Run middleware synchronously
    // This allows you to handle each result before moving to the next
    for (const fn of middlewareFunctions) {
        const result = await fn;

        if (!result.ok) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    // const nextUrl = req.nextUrl.pathname
    return NextResponse.next();

    // Option 2: Run middleware asynchronously
    // Using Promise.allSettled allows concurrent execution
   /*
    const results = await Promise.allSettled(middlewareFunctions);

    // Check each result
    for (const result of results) {
        // If rejected or not OK, return first response
        if (result.status === "fulfilled" && !result.value?.ok) {
            return result.value;
        } else if (result.status === "rejected") {
            throw result.reason
        }
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
    */
}

export const config = {
    matcher: "/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only export one middleware function.

[From Next.js 13 document](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#conditional-statements)

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/about')) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/about-2', request.url))
  }
 
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/dashboard/user', request.url))
  }
}
```

In your case, you should move the condition in `middleware2` to `middleware`

```
export function middleware(req: any) {
   // From middleware2
    
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/about')){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
    }

    let lng
    if (req.cookies.has(cookieName)) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value)

    // automatic detect language with browser
    // if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get('Accept-Language'))
    
    if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng
    
    // Redirect if lng in path is not supported
    if (
        !languages.some(loc => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')
    ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
    }
    
    if (req.headers.has('referer')) {
        const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get('referer'))
        const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) => refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`))
        const response = NextResponse.next()
        if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer)
        return response
    }

    return NextResponse.next()

}
```

In addition, the config does not have the `api` property. The `matcher` property gives you the option to run the middleware on specific routes. The config you have below will prevent your middleware from running if the request path is any of `/api`, `/_next/static`, `/_next/image`, `/assets`, `/favicon.ico` and `/sw`

```
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)']
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I should change this part of the code: 

```
export const config = { api: { bodyParser: false, }, matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)'] }
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you are trying to use two middleware functions (middleware and middleware2) in the same file. However, Next.js only allows one exported middleware function per file.

If you want to use multiple middleware functions, you should create separate files for each middleware function. For example, you could have a middleware1.js file for your first middleware function and a middleware2.js file for your second middleware function.

Here's how you could separate your middleware functions into two files:

middleware1.js

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import acceptLanguage from 'accept-language'
import { fallbackLng, languages } from './app/i18n/settings'

acceptLanguage.languages(languages)

const cookieName = 'i18next'

export function middleware(req: any) {
  let lng
  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName)) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value)

  if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng

  if (
    !languages.some(loc => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
  }

  if (req.headers.has('referer')) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get('referer'))
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) => refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`))
    const response = NextResponse.next()
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer)
    return response
  }

  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)']
}
```

middleware2.js

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/about')){
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
  }
}
```

Remember to import and use these middleware functions in the appropriate places in your application.

Comment: Do I need to import these two middleware in one file as the main file for middleware?

Comment: You can import multiple middlewares in one file. Just import them everywhere where they are needed. Try and let me know.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow, CyberJ.

It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since at least *eight* of of your answers yesterday appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.